# How to use node8 in dialogflow inline fullfillment editor?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I want to use node 8 to use async/await in dialogflow fullfillment using the inline editor (!).

I added `"engines": { "node": "8" }` in `package.json` (and used high enough versions of `firebase-admin`/`firebase-functions` there) however during deployment `async` still gives a syntax error and the firebase funtions dashboard still says node 6.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution? It's been annoying me too

Comment: Unfortunately I have still no solution.